# Is it possible to create a pull request and set the author?

Tags: azure-devops

Requirement:

We need the ability to create a PR automatically when a **new** branch is pushed to our Git repo in Azure Devops. The name of the branch is validated inside a git hook. It needs to have a certain format. The name of the branch contains the jira story number and the target branch.

Until now we are able the trigger a pipeline that will extract all the necessary information from the branch and create a PR through the Azure CLI. But our pipeline is run by the build service user. this means that the author of the branch is always the Build Service user.

Is it possible to set the author to the creator of the branch?

- Created the build pipeline to create the PR
- The pipeline extracts information form the branch (name)
- Creates the PR through the Azure CLI